# How to add data to Kendo Chart without refreshing the entire chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

We have dynamic data coming in at about 1 request per second. We would like our Kendo UI Line Chart to update with the additional data.

However, every time a new piece of data is inserted, the entire chart gets re-drawn.

Is there a way to add data to the line graph without refreshing the entire chart every time?

```
function success(obj) {
    kendochart.dataSource.add(obj);     //forces an entire redraw of chart
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is supported, but turning off transitions helps: $("#chart").kendoChart({ transitions: false, ... });

Comment: As per my knowledge this is not possible.